Help identifying bathroom exhaust fan make & model
Can anyone help identify the make or type of this bathroom exhaust fan? I want to replace the motor/fan part that I’m holding. It’s a combination fan and light. The shaft that supports the rotating blades is horizontal. The fan drum has a diameter of about 9.45 cm or 3 23/32 inch.
The sticker on the upper housing has been painted over; only a separate small “0390” sticker is visible but it doesn’t look like a model number.






Can you clean all the dust and grime off the motor to reveal any p/n?

The design indicates that it is very old.  Trying to find exact parts is probably fruitless.   However the make and model is unimportant as you need to match up the motor.
Most of the motors are still available as generic. Most come without the impeller (fan), but that can be switched to the new motor. As does the mounting bracket.
As others have suggested, clean the motor off and look for any info there. Begin your search online. A quick search netted me A universal fan motor. This could fit your needs.
You can also try to take it to your local electric supply house.

I’ll look on the motor in the next day or two. Thank you.

These motors are impedence protected or have an inline thermostat.  Does it make any noise when plugged in and 110 volts to it?  Does the shaft turn freely? Put a little oil on each end of the shaft…try to get the cotton bearing wick to saturate and try again.   If it has a bulge under tape around coil…fuse has probably popped due to bearing drag and heat generated. C frame motors normally have same bolt circle and shaft diameter so cleans the plastic parts and put a new motor in it.  Frank slightom
